# configure Monit application on Linux Centos error message

Tags: linux, centos, monit

I'm trying to configure Monit to monitor my pidfile. I had no problem except for one.
this is what I configured:

```
check process chat with pidfile /var/run/chat.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/chat start"
start program = "/etc/init.d/chat stop"
```

this is the process I have when I start chat with /etc/init.d/chat:

```
ps -ef | grep chat
root     17659     1  0 19:23 pts/2    00:00:00 /usr/bin/php -q /usr/statistic/chatManager
root     17662 17659  0 19:23 pts/2    00:00:00 /usr/bin/php -q /usr/statistic/chatManager
```

this is what I see in the monit log file:

when I start the process:

```
[GMT Mar 21 19:23:51] info     : 'chat' process is running with pid 17659
```

**when I stop the process:**

```
**[GMT Mar 21 19:23:11] error    : monit: Start or stop method not defined -- process chat**
```

any suggestions?
thanks!!
E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
check process chat with pidfile /var/run/chat.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/chat start"
start program = "/etc/init.d/chat stop"
if failed host 192.0.2.10 port XX then restart
if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

The IP has to be changed of course, as well as the port.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
stop program = "/etc/init.d/chat stop"
```

instead of

```
start program = "/etc/init.d/chat stop"
```

You wrote **start program** for both, the start and the stop program.